# PuTTY 0.61 select duplicate session from top left no longer works

Tags: putty

when in a PuTTY session with new 0.61 and you select Duplicate session, nothing happens
previously in 0.60 another session would appear enabling you to have another login to the host you are connected too

any ideas why this no longer works

Comment: I'm having similar problem. Windows 7 64-bit. PuTTYTray 0.62

Answer (score 3):

> A.7.25 When I put PuTTY in C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32 on my 64-bit Windows system, ‘Duplicate Session’ doesn't work.
>
> The short answer is not to put the PuTTY executables in that location.
>
> On 64-bit systems, C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32 is intended to contain only 64-bit binaries; Windows' 32-bit binaries live in C:\WINDOWS\SYSWOW64. When a 32-bit program such as PuTTY runs on a 64-bit system, it cannot by default see the ‘real’ C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32 at all, because the File System Redirector arranges that the running program sees the appropriate kind of binaries in SYSTEM32. Thus, operations in the PuTTY suite that involve it accessing its own executables, such as ‘New Session’ and ‘Duplicate Session’, will not work.

TL;DR: Solution is to move PuTTY executable to a directory suitable for 32-bit programs.

source: [http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-system32](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-system32)

Answer (score 1):

Check if the putty.exe is not in a protected directory (like c:\windows)

I had the same issue and when I moved the putty.exe to another directory (in my case d:\tools), I could again open a duplicate session with the menu.

Answer (score 0):

I found workable solutions which serves same thing.

- Example Putty Directory d:\putty
- Edit environment variable right click This PC--> System --> Advance System Settings --> Advance -- Environment Variable
- In System Variable edit PATH variable
- Append at the Last ;d:\putty
- now type putty in run and it works with all it function.
- remove putty exe if you have copied in system32
- tested in Windows 8.1 x64